# Not possible to click on systray

Tags: unity, unity-2d

When I am using Unity 3D, clicking on the systray doesn't work. For example, in the picture bellow:

[image: unity systray]

if I want to click on the Pidgin, Ubuntu One, Synapse,... icon, it doesn't work at all, meaning that nothing happens. I have to click on the Datetime indicator and after that go with the mouse on the left side until I reach to the desired application.

With Unity 2D this is not happening, everything is OK.

I have used this tutorial to enable the notification area: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this problem when I set the systray whitelist to `'all'` (under *desktop->unity->panel* in `dconf-editor`).
If you also set it try going back to selectively whitelisting all applications you would like to appear.

For me it solved the problem and I hope that it will for you too.

Answer (score 0):

What have you done to your panel? One of the main goals of Unity, is to remove that horrible "systray" functionality from Windows 95.

You provide so very little information that it becomes difficult to help you and that seems to be a very customized ... something. If those *are* indicators, then you can try to restart them by pressing alt+f2 and typing `killall unity-panel-service`